# Google Cloud Storage: Uploaded Media files is corrupted using XML API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I just upload the files to google cloud storage using signed url with Ajax Upload.

```
function uploadToGCS(url,file,callback) {
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

  //PROGRESS HANDLER
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
      var percent = ((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
      if(callback != null) {
        callback(0,Math.round(percent));
      }
    }

  }, false);

  //COMPLETE HANDLER
  ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    if(callback != null) {
      callback(1,0);
    }
  }, false);

  //ERROR HANDLER
  ajax.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
    if(callback != null) {
      callback(-1,0);
    }
  }, false);

  //ABORT HANDLER
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", function(event) {
    if(callback != null) {
      callback(-2,0);
    }
  }, false);

  ajax.open("PUT", url,true);
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', file);

  ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);    
  ajax.send(fd);
}
```

It's uploaded completely. But trying download the files from Bucket, Files are corrupted like media files only otherwise pdf, txt files are working fine. Have any tips please suggest me thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue by send the file directly without form data.

Like this:

```
ajax.open("PUT", url,true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);    
ajax.send(file);
```